# Change iframe in jQuery, (content not url)

Tags: jquery, iframe

I am currently creating an email plugin for a stats/reporting package we use. 
We use a third party mail distributor who run a pretty cool mail management package.

The upshot is that I'm trying to develop a plugin that allows us to preview the emails before they're sent. The mail client offer a simple JSON lookup, and this seems to fit the bill.

I'm previewing this content in an iframe in order to separate possbly contradicting CSS etc.

However: I don't actually know how to change the content in an iframe.

To be clear as well: I don't want to change the URL, I want to entirely re-write the content of the iframe. I've looked around an no one seems to tackle that specific problem... they only change the URL.

SO here's the question in pseudo-code:

[this function is called onMouseUp() from a select pull down in HTML]

```
var replacement = '<div>Hello world. This is new content.</div>';

$('epframe').CompletelyReplace(replacement)
```

I'm sure it's not too hard, but I'm not the best at jQuery/Javascript, so does anyone have any pointers?

Many thanks.
Rick

Comment: Is the iframe pointing at your server, or the mail server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#target').mouseup(function() {
      var replacement = '<div>Hello world. This is new content.</div>';    
      $('#epframe').contents().find('html').html(replacement);
   });
});
```

It will work on same domain, check out [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) for more details.

Comment: Pretty good, but not quite. I was looking to replace the whole HTML, not just the body, as I'll need to modify head (for css etc)... I've modified the above code to be:

    $('#epframe').contents().find('html').html(replacement);


This seems to work. I'd recommend you update your answer too. Accepting now.

Comment: Oh - and with ref to same origin.. the point of the iframe is to maintain complete separation of css etc. 
I'm simply dumping a a variable, instead of the URL, so there's no cross domain problems. :)